# SQL: Display "01 Mar 2017" instead of "2017-03-01" ISSUE WITH GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code below that works fine, but **I would like to change the shape of dates to look like "01 Mar 2017" instead of "2017-03-01"**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
(   
    SELECT
        [MessageType].[Name],
        CASE WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM-dd') LIKE '2017-03%' ) THEN Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             ELSE NULL                                                          
             END AS [Time],
        COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM @Table
    INNER JOIN @Table ON
    GROUP BY Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
             [MessageType].[Name]
) s
WHERE ( [Time] IS NOT NULL )
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

**OUTUPUT :**

```
NAME_______TIME______COUNT____
HTTP    2017-03-01    21
HTTP    2017-03-02    37
HTTP    2017-03-03    42
.
.
HTTP    2017-03-31    29
```

- But if I use **CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106)** after **THEN** in my code, there is a problem with **GROUP**ING so I don't get the dates counted right anymore

**WHAT HAPPENS IF I TRY TO USE**  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106)  **IN CODE:**

// everything that was changed is comented... 2 things

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
(   
    SELECT
        [MessageType].[Name],
        CASE WHEN ( Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM-dd') LIKE '2017-03%' ) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106)     --Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             ELSE NULL                                                          
             END AS [Time],
        COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM @Table 
    INNER JOIN @Table ON
    GROUP BY [OccuredAtUtc],    --Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             [MessageType].[Name]
) s
WHERE ( [Time] IS NOT NULL )
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

**I GET THIS NON GROUPED OUTPUT:**

```
HTTP    01 Mar 2017 1
HTTP    01 Mar 2017 1
HTTP    01 Mar 2017 1
HTTP    01 Mar 2017 2
HTTP    01 Mar 2017 1
HTTP    01 Mar 2017 1
.
.
HTTP    02 Mar 2017 1
.
.
HTTP    31 Mar 2017 1
```

Guess there is some problem with the data type

or with the **GROUP BY [OccuredAtUtc]... (5 lines from the end)** ...   There will jump an error if I use the whole "CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106)" in the GROUP BY too

IS THERE SOME SIMPLY SOLUTION TO THIS? I JUST NEED TO GET OUTPUT OF DATES IN FORMAT LIKE "01 Mar 2017" ...

> Original dates in [OccuredAtUtc]:

```
2017-03-01 12:16:58.5080000
2017-03-01 18:11:53.3090000
2017-03-01 18:34:18.3090000
2017-03-01 20:42:28.8570000
2017-03-01 21:10:36.7070000
.
.
.
```

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Instead of use convert in the inner select query. Can you try the convert in the external select ,In place of select *  use select colnames, convert(varchar(11),datecolumn,106)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems needlessly complicated.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT [MessageType].[Name],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106) AS [Time],
       COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM @Table t INNER JOIN  -- I assume these table names are not the real name
     @Table t2
     ON . . .
WHERE OccuredAtUtc >= '2017-03-01' AND
      OccuredAtUtc < '2017-04-01'
GROUP BY (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106),
         [MessageType].[Name]
```

Notes:

- You don't need a subquery.
- The `FROM` clause is overly simplified; I assume the table names are not both `@table`.
- Use a `where` clause to filter *before* the aggregation.  This is more efficient than filtering *after* the aggregation.
- Direct comparisons on the date is more efficient than using a function call on the column (an index can be used to filter the rows).

Comment: Thank You very much @Gordon Linof ! This helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012+, you could use `FORMAT` function, which is `FORMAT(DateColumn,'dd MMM yyyy')`